# how to resize / lvm partition

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, partition, lvm

I have a debian linux with this output of `df` command:

```
root@debian:~# df -Th
Filesystem                  Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                        devtmpfs  973M     0  973M   0% /dev
tmpfs                       tmpfs     198M  3.0M  195M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root ext4       17G  1.3G   15G   9% /
tmpfs                       tmpfs     987M     0  987M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                       tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       tmpfs     987M     0  987M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                   ext2      236M   77M  147M  35% /boot
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-home ext4       31G   49M   29G   1% /home
tmpfs                       tmpfs     198M     0  198M   0% /run/user/0
```

How can I reduce or expand the size of / partition. I am not allowed to use `umount`  command. How is it possible?

## Update

You see I can't use `umount` command here. So this is not possible to use `e2fsck` and `resize2fs` commands.

## Update2

This is the more detailed:

```
root@debian:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  debian-vg   1   3   0 wz--n- <49.76g    0 
root@debian:~# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0   50G  0 disk 
├─sda1                  8:1    0  243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                  8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                  8:5    0 49.8G  0 part 
  ├─debian--vg-root   254:0    0 16.6G  0 lvm  /
  ├─debian--vg-swap_1 254:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─debian--vg-home   254:2    0 31.2G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                    11:0    1  319M  0 rom
```

Comment: `ext4` will allow you to grow the file system while mounted. Shrinking requires the file system to be unmounted. Do you want to grow the partition, or shrink it?

Comment: @Haxiel, thank you for response. Would you please tell me both growing and shrinking solutions?

Comment: @yasin can you update your question and show the output of `lsblk` and `vgs`. Also do you want to `expand` or `shrink` the partition? I didn't get that from your question though

Comment: @ValentinBajrami, I have updated the question. This is a practice so I would be thankful if you can tell both expanding and shrinking methods.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials for this already, for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime

Comment: @Panki, I want to reduce / size and add it to /home for example!! This is not related to my question

Comment: You cannot shrink the root filesystem online. You will need to boot from some rescue medium so that you can access the root filesystem while it is not mounted.

Comment: @wurtel, You mean I have to use live linx for doing that?

Comment: @Panki. This is fairly easy. You need to boot from a `Live USB` or a `Live CD`. This doesn't have to match your current OS though. Then once you've booted you can just run `lvresize -r -L -5G /dev/mapper/debian-vg-root`  This will perform the shrinking of the file system as well as the disk size

Comment: Where `-5G` is your desired number of gibibytes to shrink!

Comment: @Panki, Thank you, you can put it in answer part in more detailed to be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here is a recap.

First download a Live ISO so you can boot from. For example if you are using a Debian operating system you could e.g download a CentOS Live iso to boot from.

Once you've booted just become super user by typing `sudo su`

To locate your exact Logical volume name issue the following commands (as displayed in your question):

```
lvs && lsblk
```

The `lvresize` utility has an option `-r` that kills two birds with one stone! It shrinks the file system and the disk size on the same run. The `-r` option stands for `resizefs` and the long option is `--resizefs`. By passing `-L -5G` option you tell `lvresize` to shrink the file system by `5GB`.

Since you are using `ext4` file system for your `/` root partition, shrinking **is** possible! For the XFS file system, this is not the case.

Reboot the system and you'll see that `/` has shrunk.

Since you wanted to assign the remaining space of the volume group `debian-vg` to `/home` then you'd run the following command to extend `/home`

```
lvresize -r -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/debian-vg-home
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just wanted to be sure this is not possible in my machine and I have to use live one.

Comment: You are welcome! In addition. If you wanted to extend the `/` file system you can do this on the fly.