# Debian Stretch LVM new partiton or volume **Now ssl keys fragged** gui won't load

Tags: debian, lvm

I have recently purchased a used Dell T710,  I installed Debian Stretch 9.6 and proxmox packages.

I intend to run some vms. I installed using LVM and let the installer do its thing.

I am running a hardware 10 raid using 4 500GB Satas with a 500GB spare booting via UEFI 2.1.

I note when I open the proxmox web page, that there was no free space on the volume for me to use or at least that is how I interpreted the graphic on the main page.

So I set about shrinking the home partition which was taking up the remainder of space on the pv, and am not able to shrink the partition to create a new one just for proxmox or create a new volume in the same group that I can configure for proxmox to access.

I currently am cut'n pasting from a systemrescuecd session running on the server.  Is there an easy way?

I've been reading here:

[[how to resize / lvm partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485867/how-to-resize-lvm-partition/485885#485885])

And here:

[[Extending VG > LVM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408789/extending-vg-lvm])

And I did follow another link that showed me how to do the filesystem and volume shrink in one command...

I don't recall the link but I think the command was `lvresize -r -L lVPath PVPath`. I have provided some hopefully relevant system information:

```
% lvs
      LV     VG           Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
      home   gladiator-vg -wi-a----- 50.00g                                                    
      root   gladiator-vg -wi-a----- 27.94g                                                    
      swap_1 gladiator-vg -wi-a----- 31.98g
```

`home` is not the last volume in the `VG`.  I was reading where this might require some more complicated manuevering.

```
    % lvdisplay
      --- Logical volume ---
      LV Path                /dev/gladiator-vg/root
      LV Name                root
      VG Name                gladiator-vg
      LV UUID                txWegy-ROvW-TMSG-0y4i-sCey-JHDQ-YpKRmL
      LV Write Access        read/write
      LV Creation host, time gladiator, 2018-11-21 00:45:44 +0000
      LV Status              available
      # open                 0
      LV Size                27.94 GiB
      Current LE             7152
      Segments               1
      Allocation             inherit
      Read ahead sectors     auto
      - currently set to     256
      Block device           253:0

      --- Logical volume ---
      LV Path                /dev/gladiator-vg/swap_1
      LV Name                swap_1
      VG Name                gladiator-vg
      LV UUID                eifh70-cPbQ-Nh7l-UYUG-OHq2-Swkh-942xCe
      LV Write Access        read/write
      LV Creation host, time gladiator, 2018-11-21 00:45:44 +0000
      LV Status              available
      # open                 0
      LV Size                31.98 GiB
      Current LE             8187
      Segments               1
      Allocation             inherit
      Read ahead sectors     auto
      - currently set to     256
      Block device           253:1

      --- Logical volume ---
      LV Path                /dev/gladiator-vg/home
      LV Name                home
      VG Name                gladiator-vg
      LV UUID                Ze23Gj-OGmr-buUx-SHES-hpP1-9Jjp-cENrqj
      LV Write Access        read/write
      LV Creation host, time gladiator, 2018-11-21 00:45:44 +0000
      LV Status              available
      # open                 0
      LV Size                50.00 GiB
      Current LE             12800
      Segments               1
      Allocation             inherit
      Read ahead sectors     auto
      - currently set to     256
      Block device           253:2

    % lvscan 
      ACTIVE            '/dev/gladiator-vg/root' [27.94 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/gladiator-vg/swap_1' [31.98 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/gladiator-vg/home' [50.00 GiB] inherit

    % pvdisplay
      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/sda3
      VG Name               gladiator-vg
      PV Size               929.76 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes 
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              238018
      Free PE               209879
      Allocated PE          28139
      PV UUID               VjY4Hv-BfxI-plZ2-5A17-SCcC-pCYm-g9xGZ5

    % pvscan
      PV /dev/sda3   VG gladiator-vg    lvm2 [929.76 GiB / 819.84 GiB free]
      Total: 1 [929.76 GiB] / in use: 1 [929.76 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

         % fdisk -l
    Disk /dev/loop0: 405.6 MiB, 425336832 bytes, 830736 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes



    Disk /dev/sda: 930.5 GiB, 999116767232 bytes, 1951399936 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: 056405C6-7818-4837-92CB-E47732521E90

    Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
    /dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
    /dev/sda2  1050624    1550335     499712   244M Linux filesystem
    /dev/sda3  1550336 1951397887 1949847552 929.8G Linux LVM


    Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8053063680 bytes, 15728640 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x00007a66

    Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
    /dev/sdb1  *        1 15728639 15728639  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


    Disk /dev/mapper/gladiator--vg-root: 28 GiB, 29997662208 bytes, 58589184 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/mapper/gladiator--vg-swap_1: 32 GiB, 34338766848 bytes, 67067904 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


    Disk /dev/mapper/gladiator--vg-home: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

## Update:

I was able to successfully shrink the partition, create a volume group.  Proxmox was not seeing those volumes as available.

I guess that I need to configure proxmox to either use the `pv` that I have created or delete the new `pv` and try to reconfigure/reinstall proxmox to setup the volumes it needs. Any suggestions?

```
    xxxx@xxxxxx:~# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda3   VG xxxxxx-vg    lvm2 [929.76 GiB / 619.64 GiB free]
  Total: 1 [929.76 GiB] / in use: 1 [929.76 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
root@gladiator:~# systemctl status pveproxy
● pveproxy.service - PVE API Proxy Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pveproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-12-22 19:39:22 EST; 1h 30min ago
  Process: 2696 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pveproxy start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2754 (pveproxy)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 122.7M
      CPU: 1min 50.387s
   CGroup: /system.slice/pveproxy.service
           ├─2754 pveproxy
           ├─8411 pveproxy worker
           └─8412 pveproxy worker

     lsblk --ascii
       NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
        sda                              8:0    0 930.5G  0 disk 
        |-sda1                           8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
        |-sda2                           8:2    0   244M  0 part /boot
        `-sda3                           8:3    0 929.8G  0 part 
         |-gladiator--vg-root         253:0    0    28G  0 lvm  /
         |-gladiator--vg-swap_1       253:1    0    32G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
         |-gladiator--vg-home         253:2    0    50G  0 lvm  /home
         |-gladiator--vg-thinlv_tmeta 253:3    0   100M  0 lvm  
         | `-gladiator--vg-thinlv     253:5    0   200G  0 lvm  /thinlv
         `-gladiator--vg-thinlv_tdata 253:4    0   200G  0 lvm  
         `-gladiator--vg-thinlv     253:5    0   200G  0 lvm  /thinlv
         sr0                             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
    # systemctl status pveproxy
● pveproxy.service - PVE API Proxy Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/pveproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-12-22 19:39:22 EST; 1h 54min ago
  Process: 2696 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pveproxy start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2754 (pveproxy)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 126.5M
      CPU: 2min 22.812s
   CGroup: /system.slice/pveproxy.service
           ├─2754 pveproxy
           ├─9922 pveproxy worker
           ├─9923 pveproxy worker
           └─9924 pveproxy worker

Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[9920]: worker exit
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[2754]: worker 9920 finished
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[2754]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[2754]: worker 9923 started
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[9923]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APIServer/AnyEvent.pm line 1647.
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[9921]: worker exit
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[2754]: worker 9921 finished
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[2754]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[2754]: worker 9924 started
Dec 22 21:33:55 gladiator pveproxy[9924]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APIServer/AnyEvent.pm line 1647.
```

```
    ~# ls -lR /etc/pve
/etc/pve:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 21 23:34 local
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  192 Dec 20 21:09 storage.cfg

/etc/pve/local:
total 0
```

I re-added `storage.cfg` after the fact. But, all my cert files are gone and I am denied access to try and recreate them.

Additionally, I was trying to add another `lv` to mount at `/var/lib/vz`.  That I believe was holding me up from booting.

I edited `fstab` from `systemrescuecd` environment and commented out the offending line.

So Please let me know what else I can provide a fix.

I'm not in a hurry, I into figuring this out and learning proxmox.

I added a thin volume:

```
    # lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/gladiator-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                gladiator-vg
  LV UUID                txWegy-ROvW-TMSG-0y4i-sCey-JHDQ-YpKRmL
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time gladiator, 559220-11-12 16:29:28 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                27.94 GiB
  Current LE             7152
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/gladiator-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                gladiator-vg
  LV UUID                eifh70-cPbQ-Nh7l-UYUG-OHq2-Swkh-942xCe
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time gladiator, 559220-11-12 16:29:28 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                31.98 GiB
  Current LE             8187
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/gladiator-vg/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                gladiator-vg
  LV UUID                Ze23Gj-OGmr-buUx-SHES-hpP1-9Jjp-cENrqj
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time gladiator, 559220-11-12 16:29:28 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                thinlv
  VG Name                gladiator-vg
  LV UUID                XzlKYn-xyrk-w8dG-QNrG-kcml-fVpW-BTYJ4s
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time sysresccd, 559220-12-12 17:54:03 -0500
  LV Pool metadata       thinlv_tmeta
  LV Pool data           thinlv_tdata
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                200.00 GiB
  Allocated pool data    0.00%
  Allocated metadata     0.43%
  Current LE             51200
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:5
```

I tried to added another `lv` to provide more space to `/var/lib/vz`.  That is when I believe the system puked with a dependency error in the logs.

So I removed it and forgot to edit `fstab`. Noted above that I got it to boot after realizing the issue.

So system boots, Just no Proxmox :(

```
        # systemctl list-units --failed
  UNIT                     LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION                          
● pve-cluster.service      loaded failed failed The Proxmox VE cluster filesystem    
● pve-daily-update.service loaded failed failed Daily PVE download activities        
● pve-firewall.service     loaded failed failed Proxmox VE firewall                  
● pve-guests.service       loaded failed failed PVE guests                           
● pve-ha-crm.service       loaded failed failed PVE Cluster Ressource Manager Daemon 
● pve-ha-lrm.service       loaded failed failed PVE Local HA Ressource Manager Daemon
● pvesr.service            loaded failed failed Proxmox VE replication runner        
● pvestatd.service         loaded failed failed PVE Status Daemon                    
● virtualbox.service       loaded failed failed LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
```

```
        # journalctl -xe
Dec 23 16:31:00 gladiator systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=111/n/a
Dec 23 16:31:00 gladiator systemd[1]: Failed to start Proxmox VE replication runner.
-- Subject: Unit pvesr.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit pvesr.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 23 16:31:00 gladiator systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 23 16:31:00 gladiator systemd[1]: pvesr.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 23 16:31:01 gladiator cron[2314]: (*system*vzdump) CAN'T OPEN SYMLINK (/etc/cron.d/vzdump)
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[6281]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6281 finished
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6295 started
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[6295]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[6283]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[6282]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6282 finished
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6283 finished
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6297 started
Dec 23 16:31:05 gladiator pveproxy[6297]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[6295]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6295 finished
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 2 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6300 started
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6301 started
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[6300]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[6297]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[6301]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6297 finished
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6302 started
Dec 23 16:31:10 gladiator pveproxy[6302]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[6300]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[6301]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6300 finished
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6303 started
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6301 finished
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6304 started
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[6303]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[6302]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[6304]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6302 finished
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6305 started
Dec 23 16:31:15 gladiator pveproxy[6305]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[6303]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[6304]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6303 finished
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6306 started
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6304 finished
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6307 started
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[6306]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[6305]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[6307]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6305 finished
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6308 started
Dec 23 16:31:20 gladiator pveproxy[6308]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6306]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6307]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6306 finished
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6309 started
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6307 finished
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6310 started
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6309]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6308]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6310]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6308 finished
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6311 started
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6311]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6309]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6310]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6309 finished
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6312 started
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6310 finished
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6313 started
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6312]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6311]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6313]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6311 finished
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6314 started
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6314]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/sh
lines 1167-1189/1189 (END)
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6310 started
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6309]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APISe
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6308]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6310]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APISe
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6308 finished
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6311 started
Dec 23 16:31:25 gladiator pveproxy[6311]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APISe
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6309]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6310]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6309 finished
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6312 started
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6310 finished
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6313 started
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6312]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APISe
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6311]: worker exit
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6313]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APISe
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6311 finished
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: starting 1 worker(s)
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[2735]: worker 6314 started
Dec 23 16:31:30 gladiator pveproxy[6314]: /etc/pve/local/pve-ssl.key: failed to load local private key (key_file or key) at /usr/share/perl5/PVE/APISe
```

Comment: It's not really clear what is the issue here. Are you lacking space ? Can you paste the output of vgdisplay command ? There should be some space available in it to create a new lv if needed or to allocate to one of the current one.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I don't have time to power up right now.  There is about 900GB available.

Comment: I understand but where should Proxmox take its space from ? So I could help you create a new lv for that usage.

Comment: Yes I believe that is what I want just not sure that is what I need.  Depending on how proxmox can access it.

Comment: Ideally, I would like a separate physical partition.  However, creating a new logical volume might work out if I can figure out how to get proxmox to recognize it as available storage space

Comment: @Pierre-Alain,  I have managed to shrink the partition 500 GB or so.  I added a logical volume to the current volume group.  Still afaict Proxmox cannot access see this pv.  So I booted systemrescuecd (on a usb stick) again and created a new pv and added a vg to it.  Started to create some lv's but stopped.  I don't know if proxmox can see the pv because it was created in debian.  I will continue my research.

Comment: You should update your question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxmox should be able to see your Volume Group (VG) called `gladiator-vg`. (I found that Proxmox automatically detected the VG and asked me to name it.) If not, add this block to `/etc/pve/storage.cfg` to declare that your VG should be known internally to Proxmox by the arbitrary label `datastore`.

```
lvm: datastore
        vgname gladiator-vg
        content images,rootdir
        shared 0
```

You cannot create arbitrary Logical Volumes (LVs) on this VG from within Proxmox, but there's nothing stopping you doing so from the host command line. What you can do though is to create VMs with virtual disk taken from this VG.

Now, assuming you also want to use Thin LVs you'll find you need some more behind-the-scenes adjustments. Create a 500 GB block of storage for use as a thin allocation pool

```
    lvcreate --size 500G --thin gladiator-vg/thinlv
```

and add this next block to the `storage.cfg` file. It declares a thin pool called `thin` using the LV called `thinlv`.

```
lvmthin: thin
        thinpool thinlv
        vgname gladiator-vg
        content rootdir,images
```

Proxmox is pretty good at picking up changes to `storage.cfg` quickly. You certainly do not need to restart the server.

[image]

Comment: I'm in the middle of following your steps.  tx

Comment: Well, I managed to frag my system it won't boot now and I know exactly how I did it.  You mentioned to add a block to /etc/pve/storage.cfg for the thnlv and I believe that I only added a section to the original lvm: datastore and wahla magic it boots to emergency mode.  I was able to get in using my root password once the upon another reboot, it won't take my password.  I'm sitting at a root terminal in systemrescuecd  and have mounted the folders.  I'll still on it tx for your assistance.

Comment: Well I have looked for storage.cfg under the mounted folder and it does not exist.  I tried searching the mounted folders w/o success.  Is that a created file or maybe it got fragged there are no other files  /etc/pve.  I recall seeing other files in this folder, but Its empty.  tx again

Comment: My last two comments arn't showing up.  I have followed the directions you gave @roaima and I now get dropped to an emergency prompt after seeing a dependency error for the thinlv volume.  I removed the thinlv volume and rebooted got the same error.   I recreated the storage.cfg file and recreated the thinlv no change.  I am in the middle of setting up chroot and resetting my password. and try again. tx

Comment: Flatten the box and start again. Either use the Proxmox installation ISO or a Debian one. If it's Debian you can still use LVM. Delete /home after installation and you'll have your disk space back for use by Proxmox. You don't need two VGs. Just one with space for Proxmox to use. Whatever you do don't try changing the physical partitions post-install.

Comment: You'll be getting the emergency boot prompt from the OS. Think of Proxmox as a dpkg application that sits on top of Debian and you won't be far wrong. The OS has to boot successfully before it can start up Proxmox.

Comment: I got it to boot, but due to my configuration mistakes proxmox fails to load the web gui.  I will be amending my question shortly.

Comment: @roima  and all I am quite a noob when it comes to proxmox.  What further troubleshooting steps can I try to see if this can be repaired?

Comment: @roima I'm marking your answer as solving the question..  I just purged proxmox and will be reinstalling tomorrow evening.  tx for your help

Comment: @roima,  I'm "flattening" my box now.  doing a guided reinstall

Comment: Okay Sorry for the delay,  I have flattened the box installed debian w/o logical volumes added a phisical volume, volume group and a thin volume all on a separate partition.